# Is there a way to allow Google OAuth on dynamic URLs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, oauth

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that runs on every page of a website (think Reddit, YouTube, etc.)

I can inject my chrome extension into these pages fine but I cannot get the Google Sign In button to work since, obviously, dynamic URLs are not allowed by Google.

Is there a way to have my log in button redirect to a static domain that's known by Google OAuth so that authentication is successful and then somehow send the resulting [BasicProfile](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#get_profile_information) back to the original application?

Alternatively, is there an easier way to get this information? All I want is the basic information(name, imageURL).

For reference, I am using React in my project and I currently have my sign in button set up with [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login).

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You can put the Google login button and code on any page you want. It is the redirect URL that must be known to Google. Once the authentication is complete, it is easy to redirect back to the page the login originated from.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have a few more questions if you don't mind.

What is the redirect URL for? The login page opens in a separate window right so what is being redirected to after it's closed?

If I only want to get the basic profile, do I need a redirect URL?

Thanks again

Comment: Investigate OAuth Flows and Grant Types. The redirect URl is the location where the flow calls back with a `code` that you then exchange for OAuth tokens (Access / Identity / Refresh). Yes, you need a redirect URL, this is a security feature. Once you understand how OAuth works (implementation and security) these items will make sense. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2